# Nested collect attribute changes for ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a list of fields for User model (`User` belongs_to `Location` and belongs_to `Company`):

```
approval_fields = [:email, :location => [:first_name, :last_name], :company => [:name, :address]]
```

I want to collect all changes for user when I try to update record by this code:

```
user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

I have written I piece of ugly code for this:

```
# Collects changed fields and returns hash of changes:
# Example: approval_fields = [:email, :location => [:first_name, :last_name]]
#          res = _collect_approval_changes(approval_fields)
#          res # => {'email' => 'new_value@change.com',
#                    'location_attributes' => {'first_name' => 'NewFirstName', 'last_name' => 'NewLastName'}}
def _collect_approval_changes(approval_fields)
  changes = {}
  approval_fields.each do |f|
    if f.is_a?(Hash)
      key = f.keys.first
      next unless self.public_send(key) # skip this association if associated object is nil
      changes["#{key}_attributes"] ||= {}
      f[key].each do |v|
        if self.public_send(key).public_send("#{v}_changed?")
          changes["#{key}_attributes"][v.to_s] = self.public_send(key).read_attribute(v)
        end
      end
      changes.delete("#{key}_attributes") if changes["#{key}_attributes"].blank?
    else
      changes[f.to_s] = self.read_attribute(f) if self.public_send("#{f}_changed?")
    end
  end
  changes
end
```

Could you give advice how to refactor this method? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot of code to do something that Rails already covers for you.

I see you are already using the `changed?` method to [check if an attribute has changed](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects) compared to the current value in the database.

However, since you use `update_attributes`, the changes get saved instantly, so it becomes more difficult to track the changes. You could use a `before_save` callback on your model, which could track if something has changed or not, right before it is updated.

For example:

```
before_save :check_changed
def check_changed
  puts (changed? ? "changed" : "unchanged")
end
```

Or you could [patch ActiveRecord itself](http://actsasblog.de/index.php/2009/06/04/rails-activerecord-get-changed-attributes-with-update_attributes/), to return the changed attributes after you call `update_attributes`:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def update_attributes_changed(attributes)
      self.attributes = attributes
      changes = self.changes
      return save, changes
    end
  end
end

status, changes = user.update_attributes_changed(params[:user])
```